# Relational table query gives me a null value in the field 'id' in table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, relational-database

I am creating a query and I used the `LEFT JOIN` to join two tables. But I'm having trouble in getting the `fb_id` value from the table, it gives me an empty result. Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfeedback a LEFT JOIN tblreply b ON a.fb_id = b.fb_id WHERE a.fb_status = 1 ORDER BY a.fb_id DESC";
$res = $con->query($sql);
....
....
```

The query above would give me a result like this :

[image]

I think that's why I don't get the `fb_id` value is because the last column is null. How do I get the value of `fb_id` from the first column? Thanks. I am really having trouble with this. I hope someone can enlightened my mind.

Comment: What is the reason for using LEFT JOIN?

Comment: If there's no matching value in the joined table then null is what is returned. That's how LEFT JOIN works.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` because I want all the data display from the view. If I use `INNER JOIN` it only display the data that match from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a left join, the 2 rows in your result set image are the rows from `tblfeedback` whose `fb_id` were not found in `tblreply`.  We know this is true because all the `tblreply` columns in the result set are null.

With that said, its not real clear what you are asking for.  If you are asking how you access the `tblfeedback.fd_id` column from your query via php, you can use the `fetch_array` method and use the 0 index.

```
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM tblfeedback a LEFT JOIN tblreply b ON a.fb_id = b.fb_id WHERE a.fb_status = 1 ORDER BY a.fb_id DESC"; 
$res = $con->query($sql);

while($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
  echo "fb_id: " . $row[0] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: exactly what I want sir! Thank you so much sir! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should give an alias to the column in the parent table, because the column names are the same in both tables. When `fetch_assoc()` fills in `$row['fb_id']`, it gets the last one in the result row, which can be `NULL` because it comes from the second table.

```
SELECT a.fb_id AS a_id, a.*, b.*
FROM tblfeedback a 
LEFT JOIN tblreply b ON a.fb_id = b.fb_id 
WHERE a.fb_status = 1 
ORDER BY a_id DESC
```

Then you can access `$row['a_id']` to get this column.

More generally, I recommend against using `SELECT *`. Just select the columns you actually need. So you can select `a.fb_id` without selecting `b.fb_id`, and it will always be filled in.